# AppId SAML : Sign request

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

I have a query regarding the certificate used by IBM AppId to sign SAML requests.I believe this certificate is self-signed by the tenant's ( AppId tenant ) private key and is auto-generated by AppId when 'signRequest' is set to true in the IDP metadata. Please confirm my understanding.

A follow up question on it, is there a API which I can use to update this certificate, lets say the IDP organization expects signed CA certs attached to a valid domain name. I only found an API to GET the AppId SAML metadata, no update API was found that could be used to provide signing certificates to the service provider ( AppId ). Please let me know.

Have seen that the CN name of the certificate generated by AppId has the below CN configuration:
subject=C = US, ST = New York, L = Armonk, O = International Business Machines Corporation, OU = IBM Cloud and Cognitive Software, CN = IBM Cloud App ID

Comment: Are you referring to this API? https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/app-id/management#update-saml-idp-configuration Please update your question with links to your doc sources

Comment: thats the API to update IDP metadata within AppId. Is there is a corresponding API to update AppId ( Service provider ) metadata, so that I can provide a different certificate which will be used by the IDP to validate the signed request. The documentation source I am referring to is at https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-enterprise

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could provide more details and add them to your question? Do you want to update certificates used for the SAML provider or for something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct, the signing certificate is auto-generated by App ID when signRequest is set to true. There is not a way for a user to update it.